# Full Outer Join not working in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I would like to know the alternative for **Full Outer Join** in MySQL. I know it can be done through union but it's not working because my requirement is little complex I hope so. I have two tables master(branch_id,purchase_mindate,purchase_billvalue) and transfer(branch_id,tra_gtr_date,tra_travalue) in which both id fields will be almost same. Now I need to get the values **id,sum(billvalue),sum(travalue)** by joining two tables with the conditions

1. Mindate=current date
2. Gtrdate=current date
3. If master's table doesn't have any value but transfer table contains then transfer's value must be included
4. If master's table contains value but transfer doesn't then master's value must be displayed.

I tried union, join, etc, but nothing helped I know I am doing something wrong somewhere but I can't identify that please help me with this.

I used the below query,

```
select purchase_master.branch_id, sum(purchase_billvalue) as billvalue, sum(tra_value) as travalue 

from purchase_master 
join purchase_transfer on purchase_master.branch_id=purchase_transfer.branch_id 
where purchase_mindate=CURDATE() and tra_gtr_date=CURDATE() 
group by branch_id
```

I get values only if two tables contains the current date but I don't get any values if one table has and other doesn't

I have attached Screen shots of tables.

1. Master Table[image: Transfer Table]
   [image: Master Table]
2. Transfer Table

I tried the below query but the result is empty,

```
select pm.branch_id,pm.purchase_billvalue, pt.tra_value from purchase_master as pm
left outer join purchase_transfer as pt on pm.branch_id=pt.branch_id
where pm.purchase_mindate=CURDATE() and pt.tra_gtr_date=CURDATE()
union
select pm.branch_id,pm.purchase_billvalue, pt.tra_value from purchase_master as pm
right outer join purchase_transfer as pt on pm.branch_id = pt.branch_id
where pm.purchase_mindate=CURDATE() and pt.tra_gtr_date=CURDATE()
```

I need the result as sum(billvalue) sum(travalue) group by branch_id,

1. If two tables contains currentdate data
2. If any one contains the currentdate data

Comment: schema, input data, expected results. The basic drill....

Comment: What do you mean by *...both id fields will be almost same*? Are they the same or not?

Comment: Same only, it works like foreign keys.

Comment: @Ajeesh Can you post sample data (just a few rows for each table) and desired output?

Comment: @Ajeesh And what is the desired output from this sample data?

Comment: Show us the query that would work if `FULL JOIN` was available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both tables more than one row per `branch_id`, you need to first `GROUP BY branch_id` - separately in each table - and then emulate the `FULL JOIN`, either with `UNION ALL` and one more `GROUP BY` or with two subqueries, one with `LEFT` and one with `RIGHT` outer join.

The 1st (`GROUP BY` separately, then `UNION ALL` plus `GROUP BY`) way:

```
SELECT branch_id, 
       SUM(purchase_billvalue) AS purchase_billvalue, 
       SUM(tra_value) AS tra_value
FROM
  ( SELECT branch_id, 
           SUM(purchase_billvalue) AS purchase_billvalue,
           NULL AS tra_value
    FROM purchase_master
    WHERE purchase_mindate = CURDATE()
    GROUP BY branch_id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT branch_id, 
           NULL, 
           SUM(tra_value)
    FROM purchase_transfer  
    WHERE tra_gtr_date = CURDATE()
    GROUP BY branch_id
) AS u
GROUP BY branch_id ;
```

---

The 3rd way to do this - which may be the most efficient method (but do test!) is provided in **[@peterm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681387/full-outer-join-not-working-in-mysql/18681491#18681491)**. First do a `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) to find all distinct `branch_id` from both tables and then do 2 `LEFT` joins to derived tables where there has been done a `GROUP BY branch_id` separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT i.branch_id, 
       m.purchase_billvalue billvalue, 
       t.tra_travalue       travalue
  FROM
(
    SELECT branch_id
      FROM master
     WHERE purchase_mindate = CURDATE()
     UNION
    SELECT branch_id
      FROM transfer  
     WHERE tra_gtr_date = CURDATE()
) i LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT branch_id, SUM(purchase_billvalue) purchase_billvalue
    FROM master 
   WHERE purchase_mindate = CURDATE()
   GROUP BY branch_id
) m
    ON i.branch_id = m.branch_id LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT branch_id, SUM(tra_travalue) tra_travalue
    FROM transfer  
   WHERE tra_gtr_date = CURDATE()
   GROUP BY branch_id
) t
    ON i.branch_id = t.branch_id
```

Sample output (*based on your screenshots and assuming that date values in both tables for all shown rows are equal*):

```
| BRANCH_ID | BILLVALUE | TRAVALUE |
|-----------|-----------|----------|
|         2 |  72580.61 |   119947 |
|         3 |    (null) |     9940 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f47c/11)** demo

Comment: I dont think this satisfies requirements 3 and 4. Ids would have to exist in both tables for this to work.

Comment: @peterm I am getting error like Unknown column 't.tra_travalue' in 'field list' while trying your coding

Comment: It means that there is a **typo** in your code (e.g. you gave  a different (other than `t`) alias for `transfer` table but didn't change it in select clause ). Did you look at the working sqlfiddle example that I provided?

Comment: @peterm Please have a look at this fiddle [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b47b/1), the result was not expected right? there shouldn't be any travalue right?

Comment: @Ajeesh Right. I've updated answer and sqlfiddle. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b47b/4) with your sample data and updated query. Does it work as expected now?

Comment: +1 now (and you can remove the last `GROUP BY i.branch_id`): [SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f47c/9)

Comment: @ypercube Fair enough. Completely agreed. Thanks a lot for input.